# I am trying to make a 32-bit mod operator in Verilog, but the result returns 32'xxxx in testbench. How can I fix this?

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, simulation, testbench

```
module mod(output [31:0] result, input [31:0] a,input [31:0] b,input CLK,input reset);
    
    wire wx, wwe, ws;
    
    mod_cu control(.s(ws), .we(wwe), .reset(reset),.CLK(CLK),.x(wx));
 
    mod_dp datapath(.result(result[31:0]),.x(wx),.s(ws),.we(wwe),.reset(reset),.CLK(CLK),.a(a[31:0]),.b(b[31:0]));
    
    
    endmodule
```

Here is the datapath module:

```
module mod_dp(output reg [31:0] result, output reg x, input s, input we, input reset, input CLK, input [31:0] a,input [31:0] b);

    reg [31:0] TEMP;
    
    //mod.v => aluya datapath
    
    always @(posedge CLK) begin 
        
        if (s==1'b0 && we ==1'b0) begin
            TEMP <= a;
        end
        if(s==1'b0 && we ==1'b1) begin
            TEMP <= TEMP - b;
            $display ("TEMP: %b",mod_dp.TEMP);
            if (TEMP<b) begin
                x <= 1'b1;
            end
        end 
        if(s==1'b1 && we ==1'b0) begin
            result <= TEMP;
            $display ("result: %b",mod_dp.result);
        end
    end
    
endmodule
```

Here is the control unit:

```
module mod_cu(output reg s, output reg we, input reset, input CLK, input x);
    
    reg [1:0] curr_state, next_state;
    localparam START = 2'b00;
    localparam COMP = 2'b01;
    localparam DONE = 2'b10;
    
    //State Registers           
    always @(posedge CLK)begin
        if(reset)
            curr_state <= START;   //reset 1, reset 0
        else
            curr_state <= next_state;
    end
    
    //Next State Logic
    always @(*)begin
        case(curr_state)
        START: begin
                next_state <= COMP;
                end
        
        COMP: begin
                if(x==1'b1)
                    next_state <= DONE;
                end
        endcase
    end
    
    //Output Logic
    always @(*)begin
        s <= 1'b0;
        we <= 1'b0;
        case(curr_state)
        START: begin
                s <= 1'b0;
                we <= 1'b0;
                end
        COMP: begin
                s <= 1'b0;
                we <= 1'b1;
                end     
        
        DONE: begin
                s <= 1'b1;
                we <= 1'b0;
                end
        endcase
    end 
endmodule
```

Here is the testbench module:

```
module my_testbench();
    reg [31:0]a;
    reg [31:0]b;
    wire [31:0] sum;
    reg CLK;
    reg reset;

    mod mod1(sum,a,b,CLK,reset);
    
    initial begin
    
        #0 a = 32'b00000000000000000000000000001110; 
        b = 32'b00000000000000000000000000000011; reset=1'b1;
        #5 reset=1'b0; 
        #10000
        #5 $display ("a: %b, b: %b, result: %b",a,b,sum);
        
    end
    
    always begin
        CLK = 0;
        #10 CLK = ~CLK;
    end
    
endmodule
```

I guess the control unit and datapath can't work simultaneously. How can I fix this problem? I can't find what is wrong in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to debug your simulation using waveforms; using `$display` statements alone is usually insufficient.  If you had done that, you would have noticed that the clock is not toggling.  You should set `CLK` to 0 in the `initial` block at time 0, not in the `always` block.

Also, you are not driving the `reset` signal properly.  Since it is used as a **synchronous** reset, you need to make sure it is active on the first positive edge of the clock.  For example, change the `reset` delay from `#5` to `#15`.  The problem in your code is that `curr_state` and `next_state` are unknown at time 0 in the simulation because the default value of `reg` types is x.  They remain unknown for the duration of the simulation because the reset condition is never satisfied.

The following testbench code fixes the x (unknown) in the `result` output.

```
module my_testbench();
    reg [31:0]a;
    reg [31:0]b;
    wire [31:0] sum;
    reg CLK;
    reg reset;

    mod mod1(sum,a,b,CLK,reset);
    
    initial begin       
        CLK = 0;
        #0 a = 32'b00000000000000000000000000001110; 
           b = 32'b00000000000000000000000000000011; 
        reset=1'b1;
        #15 reset=1'b0; 
        #10000
        #5 $display ("a: %b, b: %b, result: %b",a,b,sum);
        #5 $finish;
    end
    
    always begin
        #10 CLK = ~CLK;
    end
endmodule
```